# How to add a timestamp into a logfile with Python class

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

How to concatenate the timestamp on a file in python3.

**this is working:**
This does not have timestamp defined

```
 self.write_report(failed_users, "users_ldap_report.txt")
```

**This is not working:**  I am trying to add timestamp in the file for tracking so want to use `REPORT_TIME` to be used.

```
 import time
 REPORT_TIME = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
 self.write_report(failed_users, "users_ldap_report + REPORT_TIME.txt")
```

Note: `failed_users` is just a list .

Please guide.

Comment: Where and how ```REPORT_TIME``` is being used in your working solution ?

Comment: @Alonso, `REPORT_TIME`  is not being used in working solution i just want to use that , sorry for confusion. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @Alonso, yes true.

Comment: Check the answer I suggested below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242620/discussion-between-alonso-and-kulfi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code,

```py
import time
REPORT_TIME = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
self.write_report(failed_users, "users_ldap_report {}.txt".format(REPORT_TIME))
```

Comment: Format takes positional arguments only, Refer [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-format-method/) for Multiple Formatters